# Laravel Collection Filter - get value of filter

Tags: laravel, filter, collections, eloquent

I've got this collection filter in blade template and I want to show only the value field. Actually, I get the filtered array back.

```
{{ $room->products->filter( function($value, $key){ if( $value['product_id'] == 71 ){ return $value['value']; } }) }}
```

output:

```
[{"id":10,"product_id":71,"room_id":2,"value":"3896"}]
```

i only want to show the value field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck) method like this:

```
$room->products
     ->filter( function($value, $key) { 
          return $value['product_id'] == 71
     })
     ->pluck('value');
```

and then you can use the [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-first) method to only get the first value:

```
$room->products
     ->filter( function($value, $key) { 
          return $value['product_id'] == 71
     })
     ->pluck('value')
     ->first();
```

However, in your case, if you're always just going to be needing only one result from the filter, you could use the [`firstWhere`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-first-where) method. For example, you could do:

```
{{ $room->products->firstWhere('product_id', 71)['value'] }}
```